# Windows: run a program as different user and elevate

Tags: windows, powershell, administrator, uac, runas

I'm (at home) the domain admin and users don't have local admin rights. One user on Windows 10 wants to run the Badlion client (some Minecraft anti-cheat software), which requires administrative rights. I don't want to log in with my domain credentials there every time the user wants to start the program and the user is fed up asking me every time to start it. I've created a local admin account, but giving away the credentials would give him generic admin rights, able to install malware and whatever. What I want is some shortcut that can start only this program as this local admin, elevated.

I do understand that somehow the credentials must be stored locally under his account; that is unavoidable. But if I use the Windows credential store, they can be used for anything, not just to start this software. I thought of storing the credentials with DPAPI under some custom label. Unless he's able to reverse the script/tool I write, the password would be pretty safe. Now if I write a script to get the password from there, how could I achieve the goal? Somehow RunAs and elevate? Any ideas on how to implement this? I can develop software or Powershell scripts if needed, but I'm looking for something as simple as possible.

(Yes, I checked, this exact question doesn't exist yet. All existing questions use the Windows credential store or start from an already privileged account.)

The above is just background info; let's formulate this question simpler: I want some script that runs/starts as non-admin user, that has the credentials of an admin user hardcoded and starts an elevated Cmd.exe (which remains open) as that other user. A UAC yes/no prompt would even be ok, but no UAC prompt that requires to manually enter the password again.

Comment: You need to install the software for the users. Windows 10 gets ever more secure.

Comment: @John: You misunderstood. The software is already installed. It asks for elevation every time it starts.

Comment: You can't implement it. If you can Run As Admin a program you own the machine.

Comment: Ask the software vendor for a manifest file or like that allows a standard user to run it. Some software does this. Some (specialized) software requires admin credentials no matter what

Comment: @Mark: It's true that with a local admin account you own a machine. But if a script has the credentials (from stored in DPAPI) this isn't directly visible to the user, but good enough for me. I want to know how to progress from there.

Comment: @John: No need to ask any vendor. If I can start a script elevated, that can then start the program. The software _does_ require to run elevated.

Comment: I can replace the file so my program runs not the one you think will run. If you lock that down I'll change the path variable etc etc. There are many holes like this.

Comment: You could always set up an admin account with privileges stripped etc so it has no actual admin powers.

Comment: Task Scheduler will do what you want. You need to give them permissions to run the task manually.

Comment: @Mark: Changing programs already requires admin permissions, so that won't work. There might be ways to circumvent this, but I don't care much about this right now. Task Scheduler can do this (start something as another user), yes, but the problem there is that the started task is not interactive, which is required for a game, so that's no solution.